# Laravel Validation one of two fields must be filled

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I have two fields:

QQ

Email

How do I set up a Validator object so that one of these fields must be filled? It doesn't matter which.

---

```php
$messages = array(
    'email.required_without:qq' => Lang::get('messages.mustenteremail'),
    'email.email' => Lang::get('messages.emailinvalid'),
    'qq.required_without:email' => Lang::get('messages.mustenterqq'),
);
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

[`required_without`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-required-without) should work.

It means that the field is required if the other field is not present. If have more than two fields and only one is required, use `required_without_all:foo,bar,...`

```
$rules = array(
    'Email' => 'required_without:QQ',
    'QQ' => 'required_without:Email',
);
```

Comment: Not entirely sure. I rather think it's only `email.required_without` without the actual rule parameter, but you'll have to try out...

Comment: It's without, which seems a little limiting :(

Comment: Why is that limiting? You can only use the same rule once on the same field anyways?

Comment: I want throw error only when both fields are absent. what should id do? It should work when both fields are present.

Comment: I found that documentation a little odd. Thanks for pointing this out with an example.

Comment: How about one of them? QQ or Email not both?

Comment: Note   You can fill the both ```Email``` and ```QQ```

Answer (score 32):

In the example above (given by lucasgeiter) you actually only need one of the conditions not both.

```
$rules = array(
    'Email' => 'required_without:QQ'
);
```

If you have both rules then filling neither in will result in TWO error messages being displayed. This way it will check that at least one field is filled in and will only display one error message if neither are filled.

Comment: This is a very good point. Making *either* field mandatory when the other is empty will trigger the error when *both* are missing. Adding a custom error message that does not reference the `:attribute` that triggered the validation failure will be important when doing this.

Answer (score 9):

**Laravel >= 8.32 only support.**

Both (mobile or email) are presented simultaneously -> throw an error.

Both (mobile or email) is not present simultaneously -> throw an error.

**Allowed**

Only one parameter can be allowed.

```
'email'  =>  [ 'prohibited_unless:mobile,null,','required_without:mobile','email', 'max:255', ],
'mobile' =>  [ 'prohibited_unless:email,null','required_without:email', 'digits_between:5,13', 'numeric' ],
```

EDIT: You can also use `prohibits:email` and `prohibits:mobile` in combination of `required_without:...` rule

Answer (score 0):

One more point that I have searched alot. But I have figured out like this.

```
$rules['husband_name'] = 'required_if:gender,==,female && marital_status,==,married|string|max:255';
```

In my case, it's like gender must be `female` and marital_status must be `married` then husband name is required.