# Validation : Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In ContactsRequest.php

```
public function rules()
        {
            return [
                      'org_id' => 'required',
                      'name' => 'required',
                      'office' => 'required',
                      'mobile' => 'required_without:home',
                      'home' => 'required_without:mobile'
                   ];
        }
```

So basically what i want is , i have a form which will be taking the attributes specified in the code. But i want to modify code so that entering either one of 'home' or 'mobile' will allow me to create the new user.
What should be done.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It seems you are doing it right already? Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875366/laravel-validation-one-of-two-fields-must-be-filled

Comment: No its not working. Thing i require is that new user should be created when i provide both home and mobile, similarly user should be created when either one of them is given

Comment: what do you mean by new user and user ? is it different ?

Comment: My project is basically like a phonebook which is holding contacts of different organisations. So when a select a organisation from a select tag , table is shown consisiting of contacts of people working in that organisation.Also i have given anchor tag which is used for creating new contact for that particular organisation. Thats what i have asked for.

Comment: Code seems to be perfect for what you have asked for. make sure your blade have same name attribute.