# Validation check field not empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

We're trying to have one or another field validated, the second field only shows up when they choose to not fill in the first. So we only need the second field to validate if the first is left empty from them skipping over it.

For context its to checek the make of an appliance, we have a list of brands/makes known to the system but an option to write it manually if yours doesnt show up. But we need to validate that the manual entry field isn't empty, but only if they've skipped over the first list.

```
'single_item_make' => 'required_if:policy_type,single|required_if:single_item_make_other,',
'single_item_make_other' => 'required_if:policy_type,single|required_if:single_item_make,'
```

We tried the above and it didnt work, we cant seem to find anything in the docs about checking fields for being empty.

Only one of these two fields will be submitted at a time.

Comment: Have you tried using 'nullable' ?

Comment: We dont want them to be nullable. We need them to be validated as filled, not empty/null. The field gets inserted into a Database collumn that cannot have Null as a value.

Comment: Instead of "required_if", try using "required_without". Check this thread for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875366/laravel-validation-one-of-two-fields-must-be-filled

Comment: The docs say `required_if:anotherfield,value,...
The field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to any value.` So, this isn't suitable here. Your validation says both need to be present.

Comment: swapping the second if in each statements to a without and its still attempting to validate the other regardless. ('single_item_make_other' => 'required_if:policy_type,single|required_without:single_item_make')

Answer (score 1):

You can not combine the `required_if` with the `required_without` in this case, because it conflicts.

In your current code, the first rule on both is:

`required_if:policy_type,single`

Which requires both fields if `policy_type === 'single'`, if 1 of the fields is empty this validation will fail.

A solution might be to use complex conditional validation, like so:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
     'policy_type' => [
          'required',
          'in:single,x,y', // ?
     ],
     // some other static validation rules you have
]);

// conditional validation based on policy_type === 'single';
$v->sometimes('single_item_make', 'required_without:single_item_make_other', function ($input) {
    return $input->policy_type === 'single';
});

$v->sometimes('single_item_make_other', 'required_without:single_item_make', function ($input) {
    return $input->policy_type === 'single';
});
```

This will only check that both can't be empty at the same time and that one field is required when the other one is empty.

However, this will leave the option for the user to fill in both.

---

If you would want to validate that both can't be empty, but only 1 can be set at the same time (xor), you would have to extend your validator as this does not exist in Laravel.

Put this in your AppServiceProvider's `boot()` method:

```
Validator::extendImplicit('xor', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return empty($value) || empty(data_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[0]));
});
```

Then you can use:

```
$v->sometimes('single_item_make', 'required_without:single_item_make_other|xor:single_item_make_other', function ($input) {
    return $input->policy_type === 'single';
});

$v->sometimes('single_item_make_other', 'required_without:single_item_make|xor:single_item_make', function ($input) {
    return $input->policy_type === 'single';
});
```

In this case, `required_without` makes sure that if 1 is empty the other 1 is required and the `xor` validation makes sure that if 1 is set, the other 1 can not have a value.

You can add custom error messages in your validation or use a custom validator and pass those validation messages there.

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

I have not tested both pieces of code, but they should work.

Answer (score 0):

As the [required_without](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-without) docs suggest, you need to use it as below:

```
'single_item_make' => 'required_if:policy_type,single|required_without:single_item_make_other,',
'single_item_make_other' => 'required_if:policy_type,single|required_without:single_item_make,'
```

Comment: We tried this (noted in comments of question) and it failed. It still attempts to validate the other field.

Comment: @MikeRampling Can you show your blade? I can understand your context better then.